# Is it possible to create a JS function where members can input their unique IDs into a field and have a link display their ID at the end of the URL?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, hyperlink, user-input

My job is to create a simple field with a button that will display a URL with member ID after the URL. Non-members will display "Invalid Member ID".

I'm trying to have the URL link clickable. I'm horrible at coding but trying my best to make this work. If anyone out there can help me. Please review my code. What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry everyone, I updated the code:

HTML

```
<h2>Members Only</h2>
<input id="userInput"> <br>
Please click the link below after submitting your member ID. <br> <br>
<button onclick="myFunction()" >Submit</button>
<br> <br>
<h3 id="message"></h3>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>

function myFunction(){
 
    let userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput");
    let message = document.querySelector("#message");
    let link = document.getElementById("message");

    message.innerHTML = "https://website.com/" + userInput.value;
    link.href="https://website.com/" + userInput.value;
   }

</script>
```

[Here Is My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPJ3l.gif)

Comment: `user == '#userInput'` is always `true`. You assign this value at the top of the function and never change it. The `if`/`else` block doesn't make sense. You should instead check if the array contains the input. You store the string in `message` but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: Your edit made it worse. Now, the question is unclear. Where do the IDs come from? The edit invalidated the existing answer. I'm not sure if it should be rolled back. Are you aware that every JavaScript developer can read your JavaScript code and all the credentials and IDs in the code? If this is part of a security mechanism, it won't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by creating a dynamic `<a>` in your `<h3>` or **message** tag.

First you need to correct the condition, so here, we need to use `includes()` and your `if` will become like `if(array.includes(userInput.value)){..}`. With this, it checks if the user input is in the array of valid member id's. If it is, it sets the *href* of `<a>` tag to the url with the member id and changes the text of `<a>` to the same url. If the user input is not in the array, it sets the text of the message to *Invalid Member ID*.

```js
const array =['101','102','103','104','105'];

function myFunction(){
  let userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput");
  let message = document.querySelector("#message");
  
  // Clear the message after submit(e.i. show the 'link' or 'invalid' message
  message.textContent = "";

  // Remove existing anchor tag if it exists
  let existingLink = document.querySelector("#memberLink");
  if (existingLink) {
    existingLink.remove();
  }

  if (array.includes(userInput.value)){
    let memberLink = document.createElement("a");
    memberLink.id = "memberLink";
    memberLink.href = "https://website.com/" + userInput.value;
    memberLink.textContent = "https://website.com/" + userInput.value;
    message.appendChild(memberLink);
  } else {
    message.textContent = "Invalid Member ID";
 }
}
```

```css
div#container{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>Members Only</h2>
  <input id="userInput"> <br>
  Please click the link below after submitting your member ID. <br> <br>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" >Submit</button> <br> <br>
  <h3 id="message"></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow!! You are a Godsend. Please send me a link to buy you coffee or something. You are amazing!

Comment: I'm glad to help, so giving upvote or accept the answer is enough.